# Kids' book where kids foil alien invasions (early 2000s)

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, scholastic

I read a kids' book in the early 2000s (probably by 2004, almost certainly by 2006) whose name I'm trying to remember:

- It was probably newish when I read it, almost certainly less than ten years old. It was probably published by Scholastic. I don't remember the cover other than that it was probably a cartoony picture of kids and aliens.
- The book was divided into self-contained chapters that featured the same group of kids encountering a different alien in their neighborhood in each chapter. The stories were fairly lighthearted and most of the aliens were benign.
- The story I remember the best (possibly either the first or last story in the book) was about two aliens who showed up at their front door with ray guns, which the kids' mom immediately confiscated, believing the aliens were just weird-looking kids.

  - I specifically remember the mom saying something like "the only guns allowed in this house are Lego guns", but I haven't found any Google Books results for this phrase.
  - The aliens intended to invade Earth, but eventually give up and leave at the end of the story when they learn that "every house on Earth" has a mom.
- Another story involved an alien that disguised itself as a dog and chased the kids around. I think it pretended to sleep at one point but its breathing gave it away.
- There was another one where a (tiny?) alien crashed and needed help fixing its ship, but had no idea how its ship worked. One of the kids likened it to not needing to know how a truck worked to drive one.

Similar books that this isn't:

- *Neighbors from Outer Space*
- *Alien Invasion in My Backyard*
- *The Alien Next Door*
- *My Teacher Is An Alien*

Comment: It is also definitely not Animorphs, which is not at all that light-hearted.

Answer (score 1):

Might you be looking for the second *Disaster Diaries* book, *[ALIENS!](https://us.macmillan.com/books/9781250090881)*?

> Sam, Arty and Emmie have just barely survived a recent zombie infestation when their sleepy little town of Sitting Duck finds itself the victim of an alien invasion!
>
> But unlike what you often see on television, the aliens are very small and very cute. How dangerous can they be?
> SPOILER ALERT: they're very dangerous. And when they disintegrate the mayor with their ray guns, it’s a complete disaster. It’s up to Sam, Arty and Emmie to save the day! Again. Let the total domination of the planet begin!

I haven't found much past the blurb, but reviews indicate that every chapter is an individual story.

Comment: Thanks, this isn't it but it's similar! From what I can find this was published in 2014, so it was a bit too late - I'll update the question with a more precise timeframe. I remember that the adults in the story never found out about the aliens.